# Python Start executable then TCP connect to the process

Tags: python, tcp, socks

I am working on a programming challenge and what I need to do is have python launch the program then attempt to connect to an open sock port to send data to the program I just launched.

The program in question when launched opens a listener on port 2222, when you send a string it will process it and give a response and exit. My intention is to automate sending data to this until I find the correct type of data to send to get the result I am expecting.

```
import socket
import os

msg = 0x09
os.system(r"C:/Users/user/Desktop/myfile.exe")

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 2222
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
sock.send(str(msg))
result = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close
print result
```

The script will launch the exe but will not connect. If I manually open the file and then run the script it successfully communicates so I assumed it was a timing issue. I've used sleep delays of up to 20s and the script still hangs. I am unsure how I need to proceed to be able to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `os.system` waits the program to finish so that it returns an exit value, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

For executing independent thread use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

Comment: That worked perfectly I changed the `os.system` to `subprocess.Popen("C:/Users/user/Desktop/myfile.exe", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` and it worked exactly how I expected

Comment: @nilats you can consult the docs and learn more about the creation flags and stdin/stdout chaneling

Comment: with subprocess you can generate threads that communicate togather without external means best luck with your challenge